# Linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I am confused about the usage of `lm` and `predict` in R. I have a predictor variable $x$ and an output variable $y$, and I want to perform a univariate regression analysis. I have $15$ predictor samples from $x$, and $15$ output samples from $y$ which I will use for training. Then, I want to give a number as a predictor to the trained regression model and get the output value from the model. Here is an example R code:

```
set.seed(23)
x <- rnorm(15)
y <- x + 1
predict(lm(y ~ x), .3)
```

But the result of this `predict` call is a vector of size $15$, which has actually the same values as in $y$, although I was expecting it to be just a single number, which is the output of the test predictor $.3$. What's wrong with that code, and how should I change it to get what I want to get? I know this is a very basic question, but I am new to that stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
predict(lm(y ~ x), data.frame(x=0.3))
```